# Show if $f(x_n) \to L$, for every $x_n$ in $(a, \infty)$ which converges to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, then $f(x_n) \to L$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I already proved the → direction. I am having difficulty proving the converse.
Prove:

Suppose that f:[a, ∞) → R, for some a in R. Then  f(x_n) → L, for every x_n in the interval (a, ∞) which converges to ∞ as n is large, then f:[a, ∞) → R as x → ∞

if and only if

f(x_n) → L, for every x_n in (a, ∞) which converges to ∞ as n → ∞.

(Proof ←): Suppose  f(x_n) → L, for every x_n in (a, ∞) which converges to ∞ as n → ∞.
Thus for ever n >= N implies |f(x_n) - L| < ε. Then given a natural N such that n >= N then x_n > M.  Thus, x_n in (a, ∞).

Can someone please help me?
I am really stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L \;\;\;\Longleftarrow \;\;\; \bigg(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  f(x_n) = L\;\;\;\forall  x_n\rightarrow \infty\bigg)\quad\quad\quad(1)$$

Is this the statement that you are trying to prove?

A simple way to do this would be using contraposition. Try to prove the following (which is equivalent to $(1)$)
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) \neq  L \quad\Longrightarrow \quad\bigg(\exists  x_n\rightarrow \infty \text{ such that }\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
 f(x_n) \neq L\bigg).$$